# Completely unexpected exception: Failed to create COM object `TestCOM.generateLockPIN': Invalid syntax

Tags: php, dll, regsvr32, syswow64

I am trying to connect a com dll which is already registered in SysWow64 using regsvr32,

```
$year=2017;
$month=11;
$day=15;
$msno=100;
$obj = new COM("TestCOM.generateLockPIN");  
$output=$obj->generateLockPIN($year, $month, $day, $msno);
```

and also

```
 try {
    $obj = new COM("TestCOM");
    $year=2017;
    $month=11;
    $day=15;
    $msno=100;
 echo $output=$obj->generateLockPIN($year, $month, $day, $msno);    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo 'exception initialising com object... terminating...';
}
```

whereas `TestCOM` is my dll name and `generateLockPIN` is function name.

I also Added permission in  dcomcnfg

> component services -> Properties -> Com security -> edit default ->
>   Permissions Everyone, IUSR

and in php.ini I had set

```
com.allow_dcom = true
```

I had referred many solutions but no luck

[previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=failed%20to%20create%20com%20object%20invalid%20syntax), 
[Tried like this](http://www.joeyrivera.com/2009/calling-a-dll-with-php/)

any help will be really appriciated.